# ASP.Net MenuItem in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, iis

My ASP.Net Menu & associated MenuItems are not rendering correctly in Chrome. That is to say, they are all rendering simultaneously, in sequential order down the page, rather than as drop-down menus.

They work normally when I run the page from the solution (including in Chrome), but when I deploy it to the test server, the nested nature of the menus are lost. In my example, "Admin Maintenance," "Grid Maintenance," "Today Screen" and "Setup should all be items under the "Admin" menu, and the last 3 should be items under "Setup." They are setup correctly and, as mentioned before, they work fine when run from within VS.

A screenshot:
[image: The offending menu]

My code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu"
            EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="1">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="PTS Home" Value="PTS Main" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx">
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin Maintenance" Value="Admin_Admin Maintenance" NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/AdminMaintenance.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Grid Maintenance" Value="Admin_Grid Maintenance" NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/GridMaintenance.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Today Screen" Value="Admin_Today Screen" NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/TodayScreen.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Setup" Value="Admin_Setup">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Reserve Owner Codes" Value="Admin_Setup_Reserve Owner Codes"
                    NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/MaintainOwnerCodes.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Reserve Product Codes" Value="Admin_Setup_Reserve Product Codes"
                    NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/MaintainProductCodes.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Enter New Grade" Value="Admin_Setup_Enter New Grade" NavigateUrl="~/Secure/Admin/MaintainGrades.aspx">
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    ... //Other items
    </Items>
</Menu>
```

The weirdest/most annoying thing is that on the production server, when I first load the page, it does this, but I leave & come back, it fixes itself. On the test server, it just stays broken.

Also, this behavior occurs in IE 8, as well, though I suspect that that's a red herring, and none of my users use IE 8, anyway.

I've included the IIS keyword, as I have a feeling that this is more a server issue than a code issue, but I'm not certain. I'm not certain which version of Windows Server/IIS we run, & our server admin is out at the moment. I'll update the question later when I have that info, but I was hoping that there might be an answer anyway.

**UPDATE**
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was going on. Came upon it somewhat by accident.

The page uses mixed content (the menu itself being unsecure content). Chrome automatically blocks unsecure content on mixed pages, displaying a shield in the address bar. Click the shield, tell it to load unsecure content, and bam - no more weird behavior.

http://knowledgebase.pearsonschool.com/kmp/article/AA-05523/0/GPOINT%3A-How-do-I-display-mixed-content-with-Google-Chrome.html

Of course, I should probably just fix the menu to be secure, but this at least tells me what was going on, and *may* help others with similar problems.